# Best way to structure queries on interacting nested data sets

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I'm making a game (using C# / OpenTK) about running a Factory. The user designs rooms, hires workers and orders stock. The rest is mostly automated.

The bit I'm struggling with is the design of the worker tasking/job system.

The basic structure of the Factory is:
-Factory holds a List of Rooms
-Room holds a List of Furniture
-Furniture holds a List of Jobs, a List of ItemSlots, and a List of JobAreas
-ItemSlot holds an Item
-Job, ItemSlot, Item and JobArea hold a bool for "Available"

The structure of the Jobs are:
-Job holds a list of Items (items needed to be collected to complete the job)
-Job holds a list of ItemSlots (where items need to be placed)
-Job holds a list of JobAreas (areas such as chairs used by the worker in completing the job)

For a Job to be possible to be selected, the following are required
-Job not be being done by someone else (job.Available == true)
-for each Item needed, an Item of that type exists and is Available
-for each ItemSlot needed, an ItemSlot of that type exists and is Available
-for each JobArea needed, a JobArea of that type exists and is Available

The idea is an idle Worker will ask the Factory for a list of currently available Jobs, and then chooses a Job to do (or defaults to Idle if no job exists).

What I need help with is the way to structure the query to get the list of available Jobs (and I need to collect the information of which items/jobareas will be used if that job is selected along the way).

The kind of "brute force" approach I am thinking of at the moment goes something like this:

```
public List<JobDetails> GetAvailableJobs()
{
    var availableJobs = new List<JobDetails>();
    foreach(Room r in factory.Rooms)
    foreach(Job j in r.Jobs)
     {
      JobDetails details = IsJobAvailable(j);
      if (details!=null) availableJobs.Add(details);
     }
     return details;
}
public JobDetails IsJobAvailable(Job j)
{
    JobDetails details = new JobDetails();
    //get available items
    foreach (Item i in j.Items)
    foreach (Room r in factory.Rooms)
    foreach (Furniture f in r.Furnitures)
    foreach (ItemSlot s in f.ItemSlots)
    if (s.Item.Type == i.Type && i.Available) details.Items.Add(i);
    //get available slots
    foreach (ItemSlot itSl in j.ItemSlots)
    foreach (Room r in factory.Rooms)
    foreach (Furniture f in r.Furnitures)
    foreach (Itemslot s in f.ItemSlots)
    if (s.Type == itSl.Type && s.Available) details.ItemSlots.Add(s);
    //get available JobAreas
    foreach (JobArea jobA in j.JobAreas)
    foreach (ItemSlot itSl in j.ItemSlots)
    foreach (Room r in factory.Rooms)
    foreach (Furniture f in r.Furnitures)
    foreach (JobArea jA in f.JobAreas)
    if (jA.Type == jobA.Type && jA.Avaialble) details.JobAreas.Add(jA);

    //check if job conditions are met
    if (details.Items.Count >= j.Items.Count && details.ItemSlots.Count >= j.ItemSlots.Count && details.JobAreas.Count >= j.JobAreas.Count) return details; else return null;
}
```

The problem is, this is a huge amount of repetition and long querying. This doesn't take advantage of the relationships I know about the data, for example particular JobAreas would only ever be found in particular Rooms, or certain items would only ever be found in certain types of Furniture; at present I just look through every single object in every single room to search for each thing.

Could I be doing this better? Is LINQ an option for simplifying my queries? Is there a way to embed information in the Jobs that give a clue where to look (only check for "Oil Cannisters" in Furniture of type "Machines", and in rooms which inherit from "MachineRooms")?

To be clear, this is a question about design rather than implementation. I want some pointers on how to structure Jobs and the best way to efficiently query if the Items, ItemSlots and JobAreas are available for a given job, and pass back instances of those things where they are available (so they can be marked as Available = false and the worker can go off and do things with them).

Haighstrom

Comment: I have never seen more foreach statements within a single method in my entirely life.

Comment: I'd personally pull it into several modules. Have rooms report jobs to a 'job holder' (or whatever you want to call it). Once a worker is idle (amusing a worker is a thread) it will go to this worker class and request a job. If a job it available the job list will hand out the first job it can find for this worker. You can use locking to keep a worker waiting if no work is available (you need locking anyway when 2 workers are looking for work at the same time)

about Linq: in the end linq statements are still loops that your computer has to run trough.

Comment: I'd probably just put the "provision" of data into each container - e.g. roll the `GetAvailableJobs` down to the factory, roll the `GetAvailableJobs` onto the rooms and so on. You could do this using loops or you could maintain these lists when the source collections change, this way your API could look more like `Factory.GetAvailableJobs()` and that method itself would look more like `public IEnumerable<JobDetails> GetAvailableJobs { return Rooms.Select(x=>x.GetAvailableJobs()); }`. Not sure if there are any performance considerations though but that's up to you :)

Comment: This also means you could implement enumerators on the collections and pass predicates to the selector functions - you could create some predicate methods to help with the filtering which look at the relationships between the objects as you've suggested

Comment: I'm not using threading for this, as "Idle" is actually a Task in itself, which involves the Worker wandering around a few steps before trying again, so these queries don't happen often (2 or 3 times per frame at most). I need a list of all jobs because workers will have preferences as to which they suggest, and I don't want the gameplay to get locked in with workers doing tasks that take a long time and are low priority if there is something that is more pressing.

Comment: Sounds like you definitely need some logic which you pass to the selectors which determine which jobs to be interested in... priorities, job type etc - going to scratchpad some suggestions to your API

Comment: Since your workers act independent and you are redrawing the screen the worker will most likely be a thread behind the screen. But that's not really important as idle can be a 'user' task. You can just have your task list give them a idle task when there is nothing available. How or what would call the function to assign workers to a job?

Comment: Quick question - why does the `JobArea` and `ItemSlots` appear on the `Furniture` type and not on the `Room` type? I'm still a bit confused as to what a `Job` represents - can you explain in more detail what each "thing" represents. Is a `Job` something the worker needs to do or something a worker can do based on a piece of furniture? Is the `Furniture` something like a "machine" which the worker can work at or is it something they need to make with a list of jobs assigned to it to finish? Could you help me get my head around the role of each class?

Comment: A Job is a set of actions for the Worker to take. It's broken down into JobSteps. A JobStep might be "walk from item1 to jobArea2"., "pick up item X" (i.e. remove item X from itemSlot Y, mark itemSlotY as available) or "wait 10 seconds and play crafting animation". The JobSteps together comprise a Job, and all the Items, ItemSlots and JobLocations that are required for each JobStep together comprise the Job requirements. The user places Furnitures when they design the Room, and Jobs are all focussed around Furniture. If a Room has two Machines, there are two OperateMachine tasks.

Comment: Jobs are not WorkerThreads; this is a game. A worker is a character in the game, and a Job is a set of actions for the worker to take, which are done over several seconds, not within a single function. Each UpdateFrame of the game will increment progress of a Worker's current Job, whether than be move him one step towards his target position, or count down the timer on his current action.

Comment: The operation of the Job and the Worker after the Job is allocated is really outside the scope of this question (that's all working fine). All I'm asking about is how to get a List of Available Jobs, where the requirement for a particular Job boils down to "Is this list of things available", but the things to check for availability are deeply nested in layers of data.

Comment: If I said "Dwarf Fortress" would that fit the mould?

Comment: I was going for "Theme Hospital", but "Dwarf Fortress" works too.

Comment: What I really want, is to make use of the known grouping. If a Job needs Item X1, I know that Item X1 can only reside in ItemSlots Y1 or Y2. I also know that ItemSlot Y1 can only reside in Furniture Z1 or Z3. Only some Furniture will be allowed in some Rooms. So what I really want, is a sensible way to do a search over the whole Factory for an available Item X, but without looking through every Room, every Furniture, etc, but limit the search to drilling down only through Rooms which could contain Item X, then Furniture which could contain Item X, etc. The nesting is what's making it hard.

Comment: So given an Item i, how do I say: foreach(Room r in Factories where r could contain i) foreach(Furniture f in r where f could contain i) foreach(ItemSlot s in f where s could contain i) { (if s.Item.Type == i.Type) return i; }

Comment: There's not much you can do about checking every item - unless you create containers that group items by type e.g. `List<Dictionary<K,V>>` which I can see getting really complex - but you can improve the API so the code reads easily. I'll answer with what I might do...

Comment: I think I have to do something to limit the searching. In most cases an item will ONLY be available to one Room, one Furniture, etc. I could possibly live with that being enforced. i.e. Item X only ever exists in Furniture Y, and Furniture Y only exists in Room Z. Then I can probably use nested LINQ queries.

Comment: Have you got performance bottlenecks so far or are you just trying to avoid messy code?

Comment: I'm just planning, so I haven't written any code for this part of the game yet (right now Jobs are allocated in quasi-hard-coded way). It may be that the brute force approach won't bottleneck the application anyway, as I'd guess there will be max 100 rooms, 25 furniture per room, 5 items per furniture. I do need new Jobs, Rooms, Furniture etc to be added easily as I design content later, but to be honest this is really that I'm a bit of a stickler for elegant design.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63879/discussion-between-charleh-and-haighstrom).